# Virtual box guest addition depends on guest os only?

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I am struggling with `vagrant` , `vb-guest plugin` and trying to figure out how does on what factors `virtual box guest addition` depends ?

Does it depends on `guest os` OR it depends on 'virtualbox' version as well as 'guest os' or depends on `host`os .

I am totally confused with this.

If it depends on `virtualbox` also then if I update `virtual box` then do I need to update `guest addition` also ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [VirtualBox guest addition](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html) documentation

> the Guest Additions are designed to be installed *inside* a virtual
> machine after the guest operating system has been installed. They
> consist of device drivers and system applications that optimize the
> guest operating system for better performance and usability
>
> Each version of VirtualBox, even minor releases, ship with their own
> version of the Guest Additions. While the interfaces through which the
> VirtualBox core communicates with the Guest Additions are kept stable
> so that Guest Additions already installed in a VM should continue to
> work when VirtualBox is upgraded on the host, for best results, it is
> recommended to keep the Guest Additions at the same version.

and finally yes, when you update your version of VirtualBox, you would need to update the version of the guest addition software.

Thats where the [vagrant vbguest plugin](https://github.com/dotless-de/vagrant-vbguest/) shines, it does the check and does the install for you if needed.